# Android EndlessAdapter set OnLongClick to items

Tags: android, listview, commonsware-cwac

I'm using the `EndlessAdapter` to load a list of users from network and now I want to set the event onLongClick on each item of the list but I can't. I have set the `onClick` but if I implement the `onLongClick` it never launches this event and is launched the normal `onClick` event instead of `onLongClick`.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html

And again...

Build a custom Adapter that uses your data...

> Whenever you want to do processing with the views in a ListView you
>   need to create a custom adapter that will handle your logic
>   implementation and pass that information to the views as necessary.

Example

http://android.vexedlogic.com/2011/04/02/android-lists-listactivity-and-listview-ii-%E2%80%93-custom-adapter-and-list-item-view/